# Work item types in TFS 2010; Where are the XML files stored?

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I am trying to add a new work item type. Where the heck are the XML files that define these?

I don't see them in solution explorer, they aren't in the file system on the TFS server, so where the heck are they?

I am following [instructions from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404855%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but it doesn't say where to look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have your XML and are trying to deploy it?  Reading the link you posted, it looks like you deploy the work item types by using the witadmin utility.  The link to instructions to witadmin is below and under the references section of the instructions you gave a link to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx

Comment: I missed that step. Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

You get these from Team > Team Foundation Server Settings -> Process Template Manager, then download the template you want. Then you'll find all the WITs in there. You can edit and create new ones, then upload the changed template. Just be careful to rename the process template (inside process.xml file).

Use WitAdmin to alter existing project WITs. Use this method above for future projects.

Comment: BTW, this is helpful here! Team Foundation Server Power Tools March 2011: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Comment: When you have the template(s) downloaded, add the template files to the source control, so that you get full tracking of all your changes. The TFS doesn't have any audit trail on changes you do directly to the server.